# Inline citation of a website with natbib and plainnat

Tags: citing, natbib

for my thesis I was given a template which uses the plainnat bibliographystlye and the natbib package.

Now when I want to use websites as references I put them in the bib file like this:

```
@misc{AndroidAlphaBeta,
Title = {{Google Play Developer Help - Use alpha/beta testing \& staged rollouts}},
howpublished = {\url{https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en}},
note = {Accessed: 2015-12-28}
}
```

Now the problem is, that whenever I cite them with for example `\cite{AndroidAlphaBeta}`, it just takes the first three characters (e.g. `[And]`) of the title, which does not look all too nice. Especially when I have different sites starting with the same three characters it becomes something like And, And, or somethinig similar.

One approach would be using numbered references but I would rather not change the template.

I could also use footnotes but some websites do contain studies, which I would prefer to use as references rather than just notes.

So is that just because of the bib style or do I have to change the bibtex entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was use the `key` parameter like this for example:

```
@misc{AndroidAlphaBeta,
...
key = {Your Key Here}
}
```

Using this in the bib entry will allow the cite commands to use the keyword to show instead of the title.

This solution proposed by the user [bri-an](https://www.reddit.com/user/bri-an) in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/438zmt/inline_citation_of_websites/)